# Am I supposed to establish contact with potential postdoc mentors at a university before I apply there?

Tags: postdocs

How important is it that the people on the hiring committee have already talked with me before and know who I am, before they see my application? Is this what everyone who gets the postdoc offers does?

Answer (score 1):

"supposed to" is a bit strong, but it is probably useful to do so in most cases. This would be especially true if the professor is responsible for funding the post-doc which is pretty common.

If the call for applications is pretty specific as to the desirable characteristics of a candidate then it is probably even more useful to contact them. A bit less so for a general call. If you think you fit the position "to a T" then yes, it is worth the effort.

My usual suggestion in these cases is not to flood people with information on a first contact. Offering a bit of useful information along with your interest and a promise to send more information is probably enough.